# How to install ISAPI rewrite rule on IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis, iis-7

I used htaccess on II6,

how do I install and use it on IIS7?
but I cannot find how to install and configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install [UrlRewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) for IIS7 and then you can define rules trough web.config or directly in IIS console.

Comment: After installing, where do i see it in the IIS7 GUI ?

Comment: look at "Creating a rewrite rule" on http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score -1):

IIS 7 has a natively built-in [url rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) that you could use.